# Managing Plugin Versions in Jenkins Job's config.xml

Tags: jenkins, plugins, jenkins-plugins

I have a jenkins system that is under salt configuration management.
Plugins and their versions are managed through salt.

Jobs however are just the config.xml that are stored as-is.

My question is : How significant is the version number mentioned for each plugin in the Job's `config.xml`?

***Eg:*** The following is a snippet from one of the job's `config.xml` file.

```
<buildWrappers>
    <hudson.plugins.ansicolor.AnsiColorBuildWrapper plugin="ansicolor@0.4.2">
      <colorMapName>xterm</colorMapName>
    </hudson.plugins.ansicolor.AnsiColorBuildWrapper>
</buildWrappers>
```

In this example it says the `ansicolor` plugin is version `0.4.2`.

What if I actually update the plugin on Jenkins to, lets say, version `0.7.2` and I DONT update the job's `config.xml`?

**Q:** Does it matter that the versions are out-of-sync?

**Q:** What If I remove the version from the `config.xml` altogether? Like below:

```
<buildWrappers>
    <hudson.plugins.ansicolor.AnsiColorBuildWrapper plugin="ansicolor">
      <colorMapName>xterm</colorMapName>
    </hudson.plugins.ansicolor.AnsiColorBuildWrapper>
</buildWrappers>
```

What is the effects of doing the above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to update jobs' config files manually. Job will do it for you ONLY on the next run.